# Why does my while loop not stop?

Tags: python, while-loop, do-while

```
RANDOM_COR=random.randrange(5,6)

def check_xy_data():                   

    global COUNT
    COUNT=0

    input_xy=input("input(x,y) : ")

    think_xy=list(map(int,input_xy.split(",")))

    if(random_array[think_xy[0]][think_xy[1]] == "C"):
        screen_array[think_xy[0]][think_xy[1]] = "O"
        COUNT=COUNT+1
    else:
        screen_array[think_xy[0]][think_xy[1]] = "X"



def main():

    make_intro()

    init_screen_array ()
    init_random_array ()

    make_random_num(RANDOM_COR)


    while(True):
        check_xy_data()

        draw_outline_start(TOTAL_COL_NUM//2)

        draw_out_rowline(TOTAL_COL_NUM//2, "Input : ")
        draw_out_rowline(TOTAL_COL_NUM//2, "Correct : ")
        draw_out_rowline(TOTAL_COL_NUM//2, "Error : ")
        draw_out_rowline(TOTAL_COL_NUM//2, "Total : ")

        draw_outline_mid(TOTAL_COL_NUM//2)
        if(COUNT==RANDOM_COR-1):
            break
```

The **if** at the bottom of my code is supposed to get me out of the **while** loop, but I'm stuck in an infinite loop.  Help?

(assignment, 2016) 예고편 The Assignment | 어싸인먼트 감독: 월터 힐 각본: 월터 힐, 데니스 해밀 출연: 김성훈 출연 현빈, 유해진, 김주혁 개봉 2016 한국 상세보기 그간...

Comment: You reset `COUNT` at the start of every call to `check_xy_data`.

Comment: Try printing the variable that you expect to control breaking...

Comment: Typically, ALL_CAPS identifiers in Python indicate constants. Not really cool to be using them for variables you're changing.

Comment: Then, how can i change this?

Comment: [mcve], please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this change:

```
RANDOM_COR=random.randrange(5,6)
COUNT = 0

def check_xy_data():                   

    global COUNT
```

With COUNT inside **check_xy_data**, you set it back to 0 on every call.  It can never reach more than 1.  Your check is whether it's in the range 5-6.  This is never true, so you can never leave the loop.

Note that trivial debugging skills would have found this: just stick a **print** statement before you test your loop condition, to see what the values are.  Use that next time ... :-)